# Which will get executed first workflow or Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have some workflow and some process builder.

I want to know what is the execution order of process builder and workflow.
I have some condition where I want my workflow to run first and then process builder, its working in all the condition except one where my process builder is working first and then workflow.

Can I control this behaviour?

Comment: Workflow executes first then process builder.

Comment: but in my case first process builder is working then workflow

Comment: Is workflow is written on parent object and process builder updates its child?

Comment: both are on same child object

Comment: Is your `Process Builder` flow making changes that cause the `Workflow Rule` to fire?

Comment: no bascially I'm using Process Builder to Send only email and workflow rule to update field.

Comment: And what exactly makes you think PB is firing first?

Comment: I have three stage A, B and C and three process builder which is used to send email on each stage and two WF which change stage A to B and B to C. While creating new record on Stage A, WF update the stage to B and Process builder send B's email. But while creating new record on Stage B, WF update the stage to C from B but still sending email of B's stage

Comment: I will suggest you to combine both action in same type. PB or workflow whichever suits you.

Answer (score 10):

Order of execution of Triggers -> Workflows - > Process Builder.

Please see link and point number 12 and 13: 
[Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)